Extract-expand KDF using AES
I'm looking for a way to implement an extract-expand KDF using purely AES for the purpose of deriving multiple symmetric keys from a DH/ECDH shared secret. My research has come up short and so far I've only found hash/HMAC/KMAC based solutions. I'm thinking about replacing the HMAC in HKDF with CMAC-AES but I'm not sure if this is safe. Is there a solution to this?

NIST has approved CMAC-AES for your purpose, except that you can't derive more than 128 bits in the extract phase.
See reference: https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-56Cr2

Note that the Expand step is specified here and CMAC is not as robust as hash-based MACs/KDFs. I don't think anybody should be using it unless you have to, and if you do, you should implement the key control mitigation.
